# blocking ip address with netsh filter

Tags: windows, firewall, windows-firewall, netsh

i am trying to block ip address on my machine by doing the following in `cmd`

```
netsh ipsec add policy name=IPSystem
netsh ipsec static add filter filterlist=BlackList srcaddr=74.356.69.108 dstaddr=me&&
```

but it seems the IP address did not blocked what i am doing wrong ?

i am using windows 8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `netsh ipsec` and `netsh firewall` contexts are provided for backwards-compatibility with Windows 2000/XP/2003. Both were good for working remotely with older versions of Windows, and for configuring policies for mixed environments. Now that all these versions of Windows are EOL, both these contexts have become deprecated.

For these features in all *current* versions of Windows, use the [`netsh advfirewall` context](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771920(v=ws.10).aspx) instead.

(Even before, you would have used `netsh firewall` instead of `netsh ipsec` for blocking an IP address. Secondly, [`netsh ipsec`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725926(v=ws.10).aspx) doesn't have command `add` (including `add policy`), but only `static add filter|filter(action|list)|policy|rule` and `dynamic add (q|m)mpolicy|rule`.)

For blocking a single IP (`198.51.100.108` from [RFC 5737](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737#section-3) `TEST-NET-2`):

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IP Block" ^
   dir=in interface=any action=block remoteip=198.51.100.108/32
```

You can now see your rule with `netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="IP Block"`:

```
Rule Name:                            IP Block
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled:                              Yes
Direction:                            In
Profiles:                             Domain,Private,Public
Grouping:
LocalIP:                              Any
RemoteIP:                             198.51.100.108/32
Protocol:                             Any
Edge traversal:                       No
Action:                               Block
Ok.
```

And delete it with a matching  `delete rule` criteria; in this case `name` and `remoteip` are sufficient:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="IP Block" remoteip=198.51.100.108/32`
```

For detailed information, see [Netsh `AdvFirewall` Firewall Commands](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd734783(v=ws.10).aspx) or  `netsh advfirewall ?`

Comment: if i want to delete that rule should i call delete instead of add ?

Comment: I find the manual clear enough, and you can get more information on every `netsh` command in with `?`, e.g. `netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule ?`, so the manual comes along. But now it's also in my answer.

Comment: Also notice that the `74.356.69.108` you were originally trying to block is not an IP address, because `356` > `255`. But `netsh` is kind; it would have guided you further with an error: `A specified IP address or address keyword is not valid.`